# phonegap-nfc running without ionic in capacitor project

Tags: phonegap, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

Is there a way to run this project without useing ionic underlaying?
I am using vanilla js and wrap it into a native app using capacitor.js. However it seems to require IONIC underlaying..

Library [Link to Phonegap-nfc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/nfc).

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Ionic for that. Ionic is just a UI library and has nothing to do with the plugin itself.
Your link just points to a TypeScript wrapper originally created by Ionic (this project is now called `awesome-cordova-plugins`).

You can also just use the actual plugin directly: https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc

Example:

```js
window.nfc.scanTag();
```

Comment: that seems to move in the right direction, however where do i find the config.xml ? This is nothing setup in the capacitor project, isn't it?

Comment: For what do you need the `config.xml`?

Comment: according to the library you have to configure it

Comment: @marius do you mean the androidmanifest ?